# Campos do método não ficam guardados após submit MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Estou tentando exibir uma mensagem ao usuário quando ele enviar uma observação.
Ele faz tudo direitinho, mas não retorna a mensagem “Update feito com sucesso!” para o usuário.

No meu método na controller, já tentei guardar esta mensagem na "model.Mensagem", TempData etc... Mas acontece sempre a mesma coisa: quando verifico o valor desses campos, eles estão nulos no cshtml.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Observacoes(Remessa remessa = null)
    {
        try
        { var model = new SituacaoViewModel(remessa);
            var retorno = await model.RegistraObsAsync();

            //Aqui é onde passo os valores para a model.Mensagem

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model?.RetornoRemessa[0]?.Message))
            {
                model.Mensagem = model?.RetornoRemessa[0]?.Message.Replace("!", "");

                return View(model);
            }

            if (retorno is false)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            

            return View(model);
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                            return View(new SituacaoViewModel());
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
 public async Task<bool> RegistraObsAsync()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GetRemessa.Rg))
            {
                this.ErrorMessage = Mensagens.RegistroInvalido;
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GetRemessa.Observacao))
            {
                this.ErrorMessage = Mensagens.CampoObrigatorio;
                return false;
            }

            var enviaobservacao = await EnviaObservacoesAsync();

            if (enviaobservacao == null)
            {
                if (this.ErrorMessage != string.Empty) return false;

                this.ErrorMessage = Mensagens.InternalServerError;
                return false;
            }

            this.RetornoRemessa = enviaobservacao;

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: `model.RegistraObsAsync()` como tá esse método? será que o erro não tá dando nele?

Comment: e ao fazer debug, entra no primeiro `if`? pq pelo código que tem ai, é o único ponto onde seta o "Mensagem" na model, ou isso é feito no construtor de `SituacaoViewModel` ? só com esse pedaço de código não pra ajudar muito

Comment: Postarei a outra parte do código que está na **model**

Comment: Pronto! Postei a Model

Comment: ` return true;` o seu método `public async Task<bool> RegistraObsAsync()` não retorna a mensagem e sim um booleano